# VBA Mismatch IF Statement

Tags: excel, vba, mismatch

I am trying to compare 2 string values at the same time - Account # and Account Name. I've explicitly set all variables as Strings, however I am still getting a mismatch error in my IF comparison.

Does anyone know what is it I'm doing wrong?

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To 10

    Dim accountNumber As String
    accountNumber = CStr(Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value)
    Dim accountName As String
    accountName = CStr(Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value)
    Dim c As Integer
    c = 4

    Dim j As Integer
    For j = 2 To 14831
        Dim accountNumber2 As String
        accountNumber2 = CStr(Sheet2.Cells(j, 2).Value)
        Dim accountName2 As String
        accountName2 = CStr(Sheet2.Cells(j, 3).Value)

        If (accountNumber = accountNumber2 & accountName = accountName2) Then
            Dim platform As String
            platform = Sheet2.Cells(j, 11).Value
            Sheet1.Cells(i, c).Value = platform
            c = c + 1
        End If
    Next j

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `&` is not `and` in VBA. Try: `If accountNumber = accountNumber2 and accountName = accountName2 Then`

Comment: Hi Jerry. If my answer worked for you, please mark it as the accepted answer to let others know it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As @cybernetic.nomad writes in a comment below your question, you should be using the `and` operator which is *logical and* instead of `&` which for strings means concatenation.

When you write

```
accountNumber = accountNumber2 & accountName = accountName2
```

then `&` has higher precedence than `=` so effectively this is what it means:

```
accountNumber = (accountNumber2 & accountName) = accountName2
```

So what happens is:

1. You are first concatenating `accountNumber2` and `accountName` resulting in a string.
2. You are then comparing `accountNumber` to the result of the concatenation resulting in a boolean value.
3. Finally, you are trying to compare that boolean to `accountName2` which is a string and this is probably not what you want.